# On appending new row in kendo grid my previous datas gets cleared

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my project,i dynamically adding new rows to the kendo grid.I entered datas to that row.But on appending new row to the grid the entered datas gets cleared.I am trying to add batch creating of records.
here i used kendo widgets in all columns.My code is

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<POC_Grid.TblProductDetails>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        //column.Template(m => m.Id);
        column.Template(m => m.Item).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" }).ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                    .Name("Item#=uid#")
                    .DataTextField("Item")
                    .Filter("startswith")
                    .MinLength(1)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px", @class = "templateCell" })
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("getFilteredData", "Grid")
                            .Data("filterDataByText");
                        })
                        .ServerFiltering(true);
                    })

                    .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString());

        column.Template(m => m.Units).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" }).ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
                    .Name("Units#=uid#")
                    .Format("c")
                    .Min(0)
                    .Max(100)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" })
                    .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString());
        column.Template(m => m.SingleUnitPrice).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" }).ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
                    .Name("SingleUnitPrice#=uid#")
                    .Format("c")
                    .Min(0)
                    .Max(100)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" })
                    .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString());
        column.Template(m => m.Total).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" }).ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
                    .Name("Total#=uid#")
                    .Min(0)
                    .Max(100)
                    //.HtmlAttributes(new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell",@title="total" })
                    .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString());
    })
                .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("templateScript")
            )

        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create().Text("+");
            toolbar.Save();
        })
        .Editable(m => m.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable(p=>p.Refresh(false))
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Selectable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.Id);
            })
            .PageSize(20)
            //.Model(m => { m.Id(c => c.Id); })
                .Create(create => create.Action("Grid_Create", "Grid"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Grid_Update", "Grid"))
                //.Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "Grid"))
)
```

)

```
<script>
function templateScript(e) {
    $(".templateCell").each(function () {
        eval($(this).children("script").html());
    });
}
</script>
```

For appending new row i used

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.addRow()
```

After appending new row the existing row datas gets cleared.I think these occurs due to datasource is cleared.Plz tell some suggestion to overcome these problem.On appending new rows the existing row datas cannot get cleared.And if i tried to add batch save to database.It saves null values only.I tried these for so many hours.I couldn't get proper solutions.